# PropertyMissing for MethodClosure

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea

When I try this code in groovysh:

```
def foo(s) {
    s.trim()
}

a = foo
```

everything works as expected, but when I try it in IDE (Intellij idea) I get:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: foo for class: Test
at Test.run(Test.groovy:5)
```

**EDIT:** Same with Eclipse.

Is there any secret how groovysh converts methods to closures?

Unfortunately, I can't use the usual `this.&foo` syntax as the code is a part of DSL and i would like to make it less verbose.

Groovy 1.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In groovysh's Interpreter.groovy there is a line:

`context["${m.name}"] = new MethodClosure(type.newInstance(), m.name)`

I think it answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for me in the groovy console and I wouldn't expect it to, because `foo` is a function and you're trying to store a reference to it in the variable `a`. You can only store references to closures in variables, so you should either redefine `foo` as a closure

```
def foo = {s ->
    s.trim()
}

a = foo
```

or define it as a function and use the `.&` operator to convert it to a closure

```
def foo(s) {
    s.trim()
}

a = this.&foo
```